# How to get the GNOME version?

Tags: gnome

Is there an **authoritative way to get the GNOME version**, as long as I have a working GNOME desktop (any version) running? Several of [these suggestions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/view-the-gnome-desktop-version/) don't work on my system, either because the executables and/or packages simply don't exist or the menu item isn't available.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

For `GNOME 4`, they use `gnome-shell` version. [If we look at the source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/blob/main/panels/info-overview/cc-info-overview-panel.c#L664) we can see they are reporting the `gnome-shell` version as the "GNOME version" in the `Settings` > `Info` panel:

```c
static char *
get_gnome_version (GDBusProxy *proxy)
{
  g_autoptr(GVariant) variant = NULL;
  const char *gnome_version = NULL;
  if (!proxy)
    return NULL;

  variant = g_dbus_proxy_get_cached_property (proxy, "ShellVersion");
  if (!variant)
    return NULL;

  gnome_version = g_variant_get_string (variant, NULL);
  if (!gnome_version || *gnome_version == '\0')
    return NULL;
  return g_strdup (gnome_version);
}
```

There's a debate right now whether this was the right thing to do, see
[info-overview: rename "GNOME Version" to "GNOME Shell Version"](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/merge_requests/1481)
Note the intro to that discussion confirms what I've been saying all the time:

> The GNOME version and the GNOME Shell version are not the same thing...

It wouldn't surprise me if they change it again in the future. Until then, to get the Gnome DE version means to get the gnome-shell version so use either

```
gnome-shell --version
```

or

```
busctl --user get-property org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell ShellVersion
```

---

In `GNOME 3`, version is stored in this file:

```
/usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml
```

content (on my system):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gnome-version>
 <platform>3</platform>
 <minor>6</minor>
 <micro>2</micro>
 <distributor>Arch Linux</distributor>
 <date>2012-11-13</date>
</gnome-version>
```

The file is part of the upstream package called [`gnome-desktop`](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gnome-desktop/) (note that some distros split it into several packages so on your distro the file may end up in a package with a different name...)

`GNOME` developers [*use this file to get the DE version number and display it*](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-control-center/tree/panels/info/cc-info-panel.c#n182) in `System Settings` (aka `gnome-control-center`). So getting `GNOME` version **"the official way"** means parsing the said file and extracting `platform`, `minor` and `micro` values.

If you play with that file you can instantly see the results :)

[image]

In `GNOME 2` the file in question is:

```
/usr/share/gnome-about/gnome-version.xml
```

(though this file might be missing on some older `Gnome 2` versions IIRC)

---

Note that for GNOME v.2 & v.3 commands like `gnome-session --version`, `gnome-shell --version`, `gdm --version` etc might return confusing numbers. Those are GNOME desktop **components**, they are separate packages (with different code, history/changelog and maintainers) and as such their version may be different. They'll report the right `GNOME` version *only if they have the same version* as `gnome-desktop` (which is not always the case).

Comment: A friendly update: as of this writing, Debian Stretch (Testing) seems to provide file /usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml in package gnome-desktop3-data . To see installation history, on Debian: zgrep " installed"  /var/log/dpkg.log* | grep "gnome-desktop3-data" | cut -d':' -f2- | sort -r

Comment: @iokevins - possible... but I'm not using debian/ubuntu/derivatives and my post isn't distro-specific: upstream, there is _only one package_ and that is `gnome-desktop`;  some distros may chose to split the package and call the parts whatever. I'll edit my post to be more specific.

Comment: I see it now--appreciate the clarification; thank you!

Comment: [here](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/linux_version_getters/raw/HEAD/get_GNOME_version.sh) is a `bash` example using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to query the XML in the files to which @don_crissti points.

Comment: Thanks, @don_crissti. Here is a Python 3 script to retrieve the info from that XML: [gnome-version.py](https://gist.github.com/ramalho/832432103b094401202d89a9b2808076)

Answer (score 3):

If you launch `gnome-system-monitor` it shows the version in the dialog:

```
% gnome-system-monitor
```

#### My aging Fedora 14 box

[image: ss of monitor dialog fedora]

#### Ubuntu 12.04

[image: ss of monitor dialog ubuntu]

Comment: No `gnome-system-monitor` on default Centos 7.5 setup.

Comment: No _System_ tab in _System Monitor_ 3.28.2 on RHEL 8.4. Just _Processes_, _Resources_, _File Systems_.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ apt-cache show gnome-shell | grep Version
```

(Vivid or Wily)

Answer (score 0):

Try `gnome-session --version`. There is a man page for it on my Debian (namely `GNOME-SESSION(1)`) but the `--version` option is not listed. Well, for me it says `gnome-session 3.4.2.1`.

You can run it in the console

```
DISPLAY=":0" gnome-session --version
```

(possibly having to change the display).

Comment: This reports 3.2.1, and `gnome-system-monitor` reports 3.4.2, so it doesn't look right. And my distro is fully up to date.

Comment: See don_crissti's answer. On my system, /usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml has 3.4.2 in it. gnome-session --version reports 3.4.2. gnome-system-monitor reports 3.4.1. based on that and a rough morning I'd say gnome-system-monitor is junk. Further exploring shows that the gnome-system-monitor version (not the gnome version) is 3.4.1.... so that's what that's reporting. *Further* exploration in my package manager, shows that I have, even with an *up-to-date* system, a mixture of 3.4.0 (gnome-common), 3.4.1 (gnome-shell) and 3.4.2(gnome-desktop3, gnome-session etc.) components.

Comment: @SuperMagic: Those numbers are fairly consistent, although it is irritating not to be able to get a definite answer. My `/usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml` says `3.4.2`, but `gnome-session --version` says `3.4.2.1` so that's sort of correct (?). Maybe the morale of all of this is that the version isn't holy; it is just a number.

Answer (score 0):

For *very* new Gnome systems (>40ish), the  file suggested in
[@don_crissti's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73225/52205) is not here anymore:

```bash
~$ cat /usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml                          
cat: /usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml: No such file or directory
```

I think that the safer way is to follow the [official GNOME suggestion](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/gnome-version.html.en):

[image]

Which, in my system, gives:

[image]

Comment: they changed the way they report the gnome version, it's now the same as the shell version. I've updated my post.

Answer (score -5):

"gnome-shell --version" is showing 3.28.3 in my terminal window.

Comment: I want to call your attention to another answer which says "no, you shouldn't use commands like gnome-session --version, gnome-shell --version, gdm --version etc. Those are GNOME desktop components, they are separate packages (with different code, history/changelog and maintainers) and as such their version may be different."

Comment: Thx. I see what you mean, my xml; 3.28.2 and by command: 3.28.3.